Spring Batch - how to drive DB column names into CSV?
I'm using Spring Boot + Spring Batch XML based approached. In this example, I'm reading from MySQL DB and writing it to CSV, but my current code doesn't write DB column names to CSV
What changes are expected in this code?
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
       xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">


    <batch:job id="employeeJob">
        <batch:step id="step1">
            <batch:tasklet>
                <batch:chunk reader="employeeItemReader"
                             writer="cvsFileItemWriter"
                             commit-interval="1">
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>


    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="Password" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="employeeItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="sql" value="SELECT * FROM test.employee" />
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="com.example.mapper.EmployeeMapper" />
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- JobRepository and JobLauncher are configuration/setup classes -->
    <bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean" />
 
    <bean id="jobLauncher"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />


    <bean id="cvsFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter">
        <property name="resource" value="file:cvs/employee.csv" />
        <property name="shouldDeleteIfExists" value="true" />

        <property name="lineAggregator">
            <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">
                <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                <property name="fieldExtractor">
                    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                        <property name="names" value="empId, firstName, lastName, age, email" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>

Currently output coming like:
1,Pranali,Pimplikar,21,pp@gmail.com
2,Harshita,Dekate,29,harshita.dekate@gmail.com

what I want like below
empId,firstName,lastName,age,email
1,Pranali,Pimplikar,21,pp@gmail.com
2,Harshita,Dekate,29,harshita.dekate@gmail.com


Add a FlatFileHeaderCallback to the FlatFileItemWriter to write the header.
